# RStudio lost focus when start up

Tags: rstudio

When I start up RStudio on Windows, it lost focus. I have to click on it before I could input anything to the console or script window. I know that `Ctrl-1` to focus on the Script Window, and `Ctrl-2` to focus on the console window; however, both of these two shortcuts will work as long as I click on RStudio first.

Is there anything I need to set in RStudio?

Software Environment:

```
RStudio Version 0.99.446
Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I know that this question is a year old, but I just started using RStudio and noticed the same thing. When it starts in Windows the cursor is flashing in the console as if it should be able to accept input but I still need to click on it first to actually enable it. Certain things about how RStudio handles focus  seem unintuitive compared to how other IDEs work. Still -- it is overall a very nice piece of software.

Comment: @JohnColeman Unfortunately, I still haven't found the solution. The problem still exist for `RStudio Version 0.99.465` on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

As a kludge, you can write a VBScript which first opens RStudio and then switches the focus to it:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Program Files\RStudio"
WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe"""

WScript.Sleep 200 'milliseconds
focused = WshShell.AppActivate("RStudio")
i = 1
Do While Not focused And i < 10
    WScript.Sleep 100
    focused = WshShell.AppActivate("RStudio")
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Save this to the desktop in a file with a name like `ToRStudio.vbs`. Then, when you click on the icon, it opens up Rstudio and then tries to repeatedly switch focus to the RStudio window. In my original version of the code, I relied on a fixed time delay before issuing a single call to `AppActivate`. But, I discovered that when my workspace saved from my last session was large then my VBScript would finish executing before RStudio was ready. With the above loop, it repeatedly tries to grab focus before timing out. Since I put in the loop, it has had a 100% success rate in opening RStudio with the proper focus. In some debugging code I removed, the variable `i` never once got above 3 in 10 consecutive attempts.

Obviously, you might have to change the path names, and tweak the timings.

In my comment above I said that certain things about how RStudio handled focus struck me as counterintuitive. Since then I discovered RStudio's option to automatically switch focus to console on sourcing. The lack of doing this by default is what I had in mind. The issue in this question was the only remaining focus issue for me. I'm somewhat used to it by now, so I'm not sure if I'll actually use this VBS script.